# Convert Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean to Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, integration

I am trying to Integrate Spring with Hibernate. However, I am not able to get Hibernate's SessionFactory Object through Spring's LocalSessionFactoryBean.

I tried the following approaches:

1) Use either of org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 and org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean class

2) Use AbstractSessionFactoryBean class

3)  Try with SessionFactory=LocalSessionFactoryBean.getObject() as well as SessionFactory=LocalSessionFactoryBean

Here's the Project Structure:

```
Not allowed to post images till I reach 10 credits, sad..
```

Here 's the BookService

```
    package com.zzz.service;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

    import com.zzz.forms.BookForm;

    public class BookService {

       @Autowired
       LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernateSessionFactory;

       SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public LocalSessionFactoryBean getHibernateSessionFactory() {
            return hibernateSessionFactory;
        }
        public void setHibernateSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernateSessionFactory) {
            this.hibernateSessionFactory = hibernateSessionFactory;
        }





        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
        public  void  storeBookDetails(BookForm bookForm){

            System.out.println("Hibernae");
            setSessionFactory((SessionFactory)hibernateSessionFactory.getObject());

            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(bookForm);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();



            System.out.println("Hibernae");
        }




    }
```

Here's The Controller that leads to this service

```
    package com.zzz.controllers;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.zzz.forms.BookForm;
    import com.zzz.service.BookService;

    @Controller
    public class FirstPageController {


        BookService bookService;


        public BookService getBookService() {
            return  new BookService();
        }

        public void setBookService(BookService bookService) {
            this.bookService = bookService;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/firstPage")
        public ModelAndView showFirstPage()
        {

            return new ModelAndView("books/Book","BookForm",new BookForm());

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/enterBookDetails")
        public ModelAndView enterBookDetails(@ModelAttribute("BookForm") BookForm bookForm)
        {

            getBookService().storeBookDetails(bookForm);

            System.out.println("BOOK DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWWS");
            System.out.println(bookForm.getBookId());
            System.out.println(bookForm.getBookName());


            return  new ModelAndView("books/BookSubmitted","BookForm",bookForm);

        }


    }
```

Application Context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-3.2.xsd">


            <context:annotation-config/>
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.zzz.controllers"></context:component-scan>
            <mvc:annotation-driven/>



            <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/zz" />
                <property name="username" value="root" />
                <property name="password" value="root" />
            </bean>

            <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
                <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
                <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.zzz.forms"/>

                <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    <value>
                        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
                    </value>
                </property>
            </bean>
            </beans>
```

And The web XML

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
          <display-name>ZZZ</display-name>


          <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
          </welcome-file-list>


           <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>

            <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
            </listener>
            <context-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
            </context-param>

        </web-app>
```

The NullPointer Looks like this

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.zzz.service.BookService.storeBookDetails(BookService.java:38)
com.zzz.controllers.FirstPageController.enterBookDetails(FirstPageController.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that LocalSessionFactoryBean is not getting injected, but I cannot figure out the reason.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE has nothing to do with your hibernate set-up. In your controller you create a new book service using `new BookService()` in your `getBookService()` method. This is incorrect. You need to define a bean for the book service in your spring configuration, inject that bean into your controller (either directly or using an annotation) and use that bean in your controller. You already defined a `BookService` property, so you are almost there.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way!